# Solving a summation with n as upper limit.

Tags: summation

How might I go about solving this problem?

$\sum\limits_{i=28}^n$ $\sum\limits_{j=i}^n \left(3i+4j-5ij\right)$

Does the "n" just represent infinity?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{j = 28}^{n} \cdots$?

Comment: I changed it. It is j=i on the second summation.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider $$S=\sum\limits_{i=a}^n\sum\limits_{j=i}^n \left(3i+4j-5ij\right)$$ and consider the inner sum $$T_i=\sum\limits_{j=i}^n \left(3i+4j-5ij\right)$$ in which $i$ is fixed. So,$$T=\sum\limits_{j=i}^n \left(3i+4j-5ij\right)=3i\sum\limits_{j=i}^n 1+(4-5i)\sum\limits_{j=i}^n j$$ So $$T_i=3i(n-i+1)+(4-5i)(\frac{1}{2} (n-i+1) (i+n))$$ After expanding and grouping, we then have $$T_i=2 \left(n^2+n\right)+\frac{1}{2}  \left(-5 n^2+n+10\right)i-\frac{15 }{2}i^2+\frac{5
   }{2}i^3$$ Now, back to $S$ $$S=\sum\limits_{i=a}^n T_i=2 \left(n^2+n\right)\sum\limits_{i=a}^n 1+\frac{1}{2}  \left(-5 n^2+n+10\right)\sum\limits_{i=a}^n i-\frac{15 }{2}\sum\limits_{i=a}^n i^2+\frac{5 }{2}\sum\limits_{i=a}^n i^3$$ The first sum is just $(n-a+1)$, the second $\frac{1}{2} (n-a+1) (a+n)$ and so on (I let you finishing the calculations).

At the end, if you make $a=28$, you should end with the result given by Frey in his/her answer.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ should not necessary to be $\infty$.

I use $p,m$ instead $i,j$. Assume $n\geq m$. Note that $\sum _{p=m}^n p=-\frac{1}{2} (m-n-1) (m+n)$ and $\sum _{p=m}^n m=m\sum _{p=m}^n 1=m (-m+n+1)$. Apply these two rules first to the inner sum, then use similar procedure to the outer sum with the answer of inner sum.

If you need $n\rightarrow\infty$, you may consider the limit of the above answer or rules for infinite series.

$$\sum _{i=28}^n \sum _{j=i}^n (-5 i j+3 i+4 j)=-\frac{1}{8} (n-27) (n-26) (n (5 n+267)+3500)$$